# Python - Get a function to use argument as string and int

Tags: python

### The problem

I want `get_scores` to take `tests` and use it as an `int` for `x > 0` but be able to print tests. I've tried fiddling around for awhile and I can't get what I want.

### What I've tried

My problem is that I want the `get_scores` method to print "What percentage are tests weighted". Tests is assigned to an int so it can't print anything unless I do this which prints an int which I don't want it to do:

```
int(input("What percentage are" + str(x) + "weighted?"
```

I've tried a couple different things such as:

```
get_initial_input function (   like this: testsp = get_scores("tests")    )
```

This makes it so `x > 0` can't be processed because `x` is a string. I also tried:

```
int(x) > 0
```

... to see if it was as simple as changing it back to an int (didn't work).

### The code

```
def main():
    tests = get_initial_input("tests")
    assignments = get_initial_input("assignments")
    exercises = get_initial_input("exercises")
    labs = get_initial_input("labs")
    finals = get_initial_input("finals")
    testsp = get_scores(tests)
    assignmentsp = get_scores(assignments)
    exercisesp = get_scores(exercises)
    labsp = get_scores(labs)
    finalsp = get_scores(finals)
def get_initial_input(x):
    val = int(input("How many "+ x + " were there?    "))
    return val

def get_scores(x):
    if x > 0:
            xp = int(input("What percentage are "+ str(x) + " weighted?"))
            return xp

main()
```

Is there anyway to get what I want?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: maybe make a dict where the key is your type of tests an the values are ints representing weightings, might be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have `get_scores` take two arguments: one being a string giving the type of the assignment, and therefore what to print, and the other being the number of such assignments:

```
def get_scores(x, kind):
    if x > 0:
        xp = int(input("What percentage are "+ kind + " weighted?"))
        return xp
```

Which you'd call like:

```
testsp = get_scores(tests, 'tests)
```

But it might make more sense to write the function without the `if`, and do the checking *before* you call it.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a little confused, but it sounds like you are trying to use the variable `tests` to represent both an integer value and a string at the same time.  You could turn tests into a string, and then use string indexing to get what you want:

```
tests = ["tests"]
```

Now you can get the second value into the list by using:

```
tests.append(get_initial_input(tests))
```

Now when you want to print the string, just use `print tests[0]` and when you want to print the number of tests, use `print tests[1]`.